# Why can't I define `Eq` using only indices in Agda?

Tags: types, functional-programming, agda, dependent-type, type-theory

Why can't I define a more explicit version of heterogenous equality like this:

```
data Eq  : (A : Set) -> A -> A -> Set where
  Refl : (T : Set) -> (x : T) -> Eq T x x
```

When I do so, I get the following error:

```
The type of the constructor does not fit in the sort of the
datatype, since Set₁ is not less or equal than Set
when checking the constructor Refl in the declaration of Eq
```

I know that this error has something to do with the universe heirarchy, but I don't know what exactly. Does it think that `Eq T x x` should be `Set_1`, or that it is but it shouldn't be? Why is anything here `Set_1`?

Comment: It's `Set1` because your constructor quantifies over `Set`.

Comment: Check [The Agda Wiki](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.UniversePolymorphism) (although it contains a somewhat misleading claim that `(n : Level) → Set n` does not belong to any universe, but it does belong to one — to the [super universe](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.221.1318&rep=rep1&type=pdf) which you cannot access from within Agda, but which exists in the metatheory).

Comment: Also, with the new versions of Agda your code typechecks, because Agda does some form of woodoo wrt universe levels in data declarations, however I cannot find anything precise about that.

Comment: So, I understand the example in the Wiki, why you can't have `List Set` because you can't do `Set : Set`, but I don't see the connection to this case.

Comment: @Vitus so any constructors that quantify over `Set` must return something of type `Set_1`? Is there a reference for this? I believe you, but I'd love to learn more.

Comment: @jmite: [`List` is defined with universe polymorphism](https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Data.List.Base.html#669) in the standard library, so you can have `List Set : Set1` (since `Set : Set1`).

Comment: @Cactus Good to know. I was referring to the AgdaWiki example that user3237465 posted, but I guess that's a simplified version of list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the type you are defining has an index whose type is in `Set n`, then the type itself must be in at least `Set n`. In your case, one of your indices, `A`, has type `Set`, so **its type** is **in** `Set 1` (since `Set : Set 1`). And so, `Eq` itself needs to be in at least `Set 1`.

Note that if `A : Set` was a *parameter* instead of an *index*, the above wouldn't apply, which is why homogenous equality can be in `Set`.